# Find function definitions in the Linux kernel source tree recursively

Tags: regex, linux, grep, kernel

I need a way to grep function definitions from a specific subsystem of the kernel source tree (lets say mm). My original thought was to search for the regular expression ")\n{" which by convention is the starting point of a Linux kernel function.

Sadly though I found out that the newline character is used as a separator in grep, so it can't be used in a regular expression.

Anyone got a work-around or another useful command?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just gave it a second thought and a regular expression that does list only function definitions is: ")$".

Since every function definition is followed by a "\n" and every other occurrence of ")" (as in a function call) is going to be followed either by other characters or a semicolon, the aforementioned regular expression filters out everything else.

Thanks for anyone putting some thought into it though!

Comment: ctags is useful command for parsing large amount of source code.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to **customize the GCC compiler** to search what you want.

In particular, recent GCC (that is, version **4.6**) can be extended with *plugins* (coded in C), or with extensions coded in GCC [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (MELT is a high-level domain specific language to extend GCC).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, what you are attempting to do is parsing, and regex is the wrong approach. Sure, you
might get something that works 99% of the time, but it will fail you in strange and unexpected ways.

Looking into using a parser